# Common Lisp equivalent of Haskell's replicate?

Tags: list, haskell, common-lisp, sequence, replicate

[replicate](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Prelude.html#g:16) is a function that takes an integer and a sequence and returns the sequence repeated n times.

E.g. `replicate 3 ["a"]` returns `["a", "a", "a"]`

Does Common Lisp have an equivalent function, or do I have to write one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(make-sequence 'list n :initial-element element)`

[HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_seq.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I know a lot of these helpful functions exist, just not their names.

Answer (score 7):

Use make-list

```
(make-list 3 :initial-element 'a)
```

It evaluates to

```
(A A A)
```

Comment: maybe `(make-list 3 :initial-element '(a))`?